# Get all max values from array of objects in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object, max

I have this array of objects i'm getting from query in mysql, i need th

```
  [
                {
                    "id": "11",
                    "from_userid": "1996",
                    "contest_id": "29",
                    "to_userid": "8",
                    "vote_date": "2020-10-06 01:40:04",
                    "count_votes": "1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "from_userid": "82",
                    "contest_id": "29",
                    "to_userid": "94",
                    "vote_date": "2020-09-03 07:06:36",
                    "count_votes": "1"
                },
               {
                    "id": "2",
                    "from_userid": "82",
                    "contest_id": "29",
                    "to_userid": "98",
                    "vote_date": "2020-09-03 07:06:36",
                    "count_votes": "0"
                }
            ]
```

I need the object which has highest 'count_votes ' for eg- id-11 and 1 have similar count votes. So the function should return those 2 objects.

The function i am using returns only one object. I need both of the objects whichever maybe but the highest(count_votes) objects.
Expected Output-

```
 [
                {
                    "id": "11",
                    "from_userid": "1996",
                    "contest_id": "29",
                    "to_userid": "8",
                    "vote_date": "2020-10-06 01:40:04",
                    "count_votes": "1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "from_userid": "82",
                    "contest_id": "29",
                    "to_userid": "94",
                    "vote_date": "2020-09-03 07:06:36",
                    "count_votes": "1"
                }
]
```

Function used-

```
function max_attribute_in_array($array, $prop) {
    return max(array_map(function($o) use($prop) {
                            return $o;
                         },
                         $array));
}
```

And tried this also-

```
function get_highest($arr) {
    $max = $arr[0]; // set the highest object to the first one in the array
    foreach($arr as $obj) { // loop through every object in the array
        $num = $obj['count_votes']; // get the number from the current object
        if($num > $max['count_votes']) { // If the number of the current object is greater than the maxs number:
            $max = $obj; // set the max to the current object
        }
    }
    return $max; // Loop is complete, so we have found our max and can return the max object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract all the `count_votes` values into an array, which you can then take the [`max`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) of:

```
$max = max(array_column($arr, 'count_votes'));
```

You can then [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) your array based on the `count_votes` value being equal to `$max`:

```
$out = array_filter($arr, function ($o) use ($max) {
    return $o['count_votes'] == $max;
});
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [from_userid] => 1996
            [contest_id] => 29
            [to_userid] => 8
            [vote_date] => 2020-10-06 01:40:04
            [count_votes] => 1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [from_userid] => 82
            [contest_id] => 29
            [to_userid] => 94
            [vote_date] => 2020-09-03 07:06:36
            [count_votes] => 1
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/hKJ2u)

Answer (score 0):

*NOTE* `max` works with single level arrays, so all your objects are converted to int's internally.

---

As @Nick has pointed out your `get_highest` can be done via PHP functions:

```php
function get_highest($array, $prop) {
    return max(array_column($array, $prop));
}
```

---

So all you have to do is filter your array by this `get_highest`:

```php
$max = get_highest($myArray, 'count_votes');

$maxes = array_filter($myArray, fn($obj) => $obj['count_votes'] === $max);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function get_heighest($arr){
    $newArray = array();
    $voteCount = 0;

    foreach($arr as $obj){
        if($obj['count_votes'] >= $voteCount){
            array_push($newArray, $obj)
            $voteCount = $obj['count_votes'];
        }else{
            $i = 0;
            foreach($newArray as $object){
                if($object['count_votes'] < $voteCount){
                    unset($newArray[$i]);
                }
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```